# Mobile number field with separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I need to format the mobile number field in such a way that it is separated into three parts as follows:

1 - Country code noneditable(3 digits)
2 - Editable 2 digit number 
3 - User can be able to enter their unique number (7 digits)

The Separation should be in the same Input TextBox where i start typing *each parts should be separated by a space or "-" automatically

I am not allowed to use any plugin. Help me out!!!

Comment: Do you want 3 different textboxes for this or you want to do it in a single one?

Comment: A non-instructive programming exercise.

Comment: I need to show this as a single text box..but i can use multiple text boxes and design like a single text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/F9vRr/1/)

One with three textboxes and the otherone wrapped in a div [Fake textbox]

```
<input type="text" max-length="3" value="+91" disabled="disabled" class="small"/>
<input type="text" max-length="2" value="43" class="small"/>
<input type="text" max-length="7" value=""/>

.small {
    width:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

or

```
<div class="inputwrap">
 <input type="text" max-length="3" value="+91" disabled="disabled" class="small"/>
<input type="text" max-length="2" value="43" class="small"/>
<input type="text" max-length="7" value=""/>   
</div>

.inputwrap {
    border:1px solid #c6c6c6;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
}

.inputwrap input {
    background:transparent;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: This is what i expected...but i am using kendo ui..so the two adjacent field inputs are getting overlapped